# Static library in C — reading files inside the library

Tags: c, file, opencl, static-libraries, fread

Let's assume that I create a library `lib.a` using this command:

```
ar r lib.a *.o *.cl
```

but some of the object files .o must read some .cl files that are now included in the library `lib.a`.   They must do something like:

```
cl_program prog;
int err;
const char *fname = "convolutional_feed_forward.cl";
FILE *kfile;
size_t kfilesize;
char *ksource;
kfile = fopen(fname,"r");
fseek(kfile,0,SEEK_END);
kfilesize = (size_t)ftell(kfile);
rewind(kfile);
ksource = (char*)malloc(kfilesize*sizeof(char));
err = fread(ksource,1,kfilesize,kfile);
fclose(kfile);
```

where "`convolutional_feed_forward.cl`" is one of the files that are now in `lib.a`.
Is still possible for this code that is inside a `.o` as an object file inside the `lib.a` library to read that `.cl` file?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but the `.cl` file won’t be in the executable so the program will need to know where the library is at runtime so it can open it.  Be aware the library formats are not completely standard. The differences are manageable.

Comment: thank you, but are you sure that the program need to know where the .cl file is? because if as fname i write ./convolutional_feed_forward.cl and both the .o object file and .cl file are in the library the .o file use the relative path and not the aboslute. is ok in this way or not?

Comment: i tried and seems that: once you have created the lib.a, the objects files work in the folder of the program that call them. so if you have something like ./main.c and ./lib/lib.a then the .cl files (if the object files search the cl files in the current directory) must be in the same directory of main.c. big problem, so is useless put the .cl files in the .a library.

Comment: I mostly agree with the conclusion "it is useless to put the `.cl` files in the `.a` library".  You could put them in some archive (library) file, and as long as the base names of the files are unique (so you don't try to store both `xyz/abc.cl` and `pqr/abc.cl` in a single archive) and as long as the program knows at runtime where to find that archive file, then it would be possible (but not necessarily sensible) to extract the `.cl` files from the archive, or otherwise get the content into the programs memory.  It becomes a configuration item — where is the archive located.

Comment: If the `.cl` files need to exist on disk to be used, then you're almost certainly better off just storing them in a known directory — for example, either directly in `/usr/local/lib/your-app-name` or in a sub-directory under that would be one possibility; `/usr/local/your-app-name` would be another starting point, possibly with sub-directories under it.  Using an environment variable to locate the files might be another option: `YOUR_APP_NAME_DIR=/opt/your-app-name` as a possibility (storing stuff in a directory under `/opt` is another standard location).  Don't forget about versioning.